# Passing OpenCV mat to OpenCL kernel for execution

Tags: opencv, image-processing, opencl

I am trying to combine Opencv with OpenCL for creating image buffer and pass it to GPU.
I have imx6 which uses vivante core (GPU). 
Do not support OCL feature of opencv.

I am using OpenCV for reading an image which is in Mat and then want to convert it to float array and pass to kernel for execution.

But I'm getting an error segment fault while running cl program.

Probably I am not able to convert `cv::mat` to `cl_float2`, please help.

Snippet of code:

```
/* Load Image using opencv in opencl*/
cv::Mat shore_mask = cv::imread("1.jpg", 1);

cl_float2 *im = (cl_float2*)shore_mask.data;

cl_int h = shore_mask.rows;
cl_int w = shore_mask.cols;


/* Transfer data to memory buffer */

ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue , inimg, CL_TRUE, 0, h*w*sizeof(cl_float2), im, 0, NULL, &ev_writ);
```

How do I convert mat to float matrix and pass it to opencl kernel for execution?

Comment: Have you considered using [ocl::oclMat](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ocl/doc/operations_on_matrices.html?highlight=rtype#ocl-oclmat-convertto) instead of the regular CV Mat?  It seems like that might offer a better solution for getting things in and out of OpenCL.  Also take a look at the [OpenCL Module Introduction](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ocl/doc/introduction.html) general info page, it seems like using oclMat should be drop in replaceable with a regular Mat and could simplify what you are trying to do.

Comment: I tried ocl::oclMat it is not working throwing segment fault.
i am using OpenCL embedded profile  1.1  for vivante GPU.
so opencv ocl feature  cannot help .

Comment: Curses, have you also tried using [Mat::convertTo](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-convertto) to convert the matrix to another type like a regular float or double, from which you could create a matrix of cl_float2?

Comment: I tried using the following syntax
im = (cl_float2 *)malloc(h * w * sizeof(cl_float2));
shore_mask::convertTo(im, 1,1,0);
still it is saying error.
i want to declare two variable 1 ) float dst; 2) mat source_img;
and want to convert mat source_img to float and store that in dst.
I might be not doing it correctly can you please show me how to use convertTo function.

Answer (score 0):

```
cv::Mat shore_mask = cv::imread("1.jpg", 1);
```

This gives you BGR image of size 3*width*height*8bit. Now, you do

```
ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue , inimg, CL_TRUE, 0, h*w*sizeof(cl_float2), im, 0, NULL, &ev_writ);
```

Read size is width*height*64 bit - you are getting over the array bounds. Convert your cv::Mat to proper type or change read size.

Comment: I have allocated height*width*3*8 memory.
My issue is regarding how to convert mat to float value which i can pass to kernel buffer. Let say
Mat image;
float image2;
now how to assign mat variable to float (i.e image2 = image say) ?







cl_float2 *im = (cl_float2*)shore_mask.data;
Can it be declared like this?

Comment: First of all, how do you want to use data from cv::Mat? It's 3-channel, but cl_float2 is 2-channel.

Comment: GPU vivante GC2000 only support IMAGE2D.
So i am confused how to process jpg image using OpenCL,
I am trying to read an image using OpenCV and want to pass the buffer to OpenCL for increasing  brightness and contrast .
please provide some code examples for this.

Comment: IMAGE2D nas no relation to number of channels, that is just regular image. Number of channels is determined by cl_image_format, which in your case should look like CL_BGRA (Add alpha channel via OpenCV). Anyway, if you are dealing with images, clEnqueueWriteBuffer is incorrect command, use clEnqueueWriteImage instead.